# Foliation values of a manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, foliations

Let $M$ be  a smooth  n dimensional manifold.  The foliation values of $M$, denoted by $F(M)$, is defined as

\begin{equation} F(M)=\{ 1\leq k\leq n\mid \text{there exist  an smooth $k$ dimensional foliation of M}  \}\end{equation}

Question:

> For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, What is $F(S^{n})$?

Comment: Your 2nd question doesn't make any sense to me.  What does $S^7$ mean to you, as a smooth manifold?

Comment: I separate the second question(I delete it from this question and give it in a new question, with more explanation)

Comment: for $n$ even, it is $\{n\}$, because the Euler class implies that the tangent bundle is irreducible. For $n$ odd it always includes $1$. Not sure in about other $k$.

Comment: Reeb constructed (in hs thesis)  a codimension 1 foliation of the 3-sphere and from that H. B. Lawson, Jr, constructed codimension 1 foliations on spheres of dimensions $2^k+3$ in [Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 94, No. 3 (Nov., 1971), pp. 494-503] So sometimes we do have $n-1$ in $F(S^n)$. Durfee generalized this to odd dimensional spheres. Thurston proved a couple of years later that in fact codimension 1 foliations exists in every closed manifold of Euler characteristic zero.

Comment: Ah! Thurston himself tells of all this in a short paper in the Proc. of the ICM 74 in Vancouver. MathSciNet chasing is fun :-) See http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1974.1/Main/icm1974.1.0547.0550.ocr.pdf

Comment: $S^{4n-1}$ gets a 3-dimensional foliation from the diagonal free action by $SU(2)$ (or unit quaternions).

Comment: Also, $S^{15}$ is foliated by $S^7$'s, from the fibration $S^7\to S^{15}\to S^8$.

Comment: @IanAgol  What about $\mathbb{C}P^2$? Does it admit a  2  dimensional foliation?

Comment: @IanAgol  My apology for this second comment.  if the answer to the previous comment  is yes, does it admit a foliation whose  leaves are totally  geodesics  with respect to  Fubbini Study metric?