# Foliation values of Exotic spheres

Tags: smooth-manifolds, foliations

In the following question, we defined the foliation values of an smooth manifold;

[Foliation values of a manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154975/foliation-values-of-a-manifold)

Let $S_{i}$'s, $i\in \{0,1,\ldots,27\}$, be the smooth structures of topological $S^{7}$.

According to the above definition, we find foiation values $F_{i}$, where each $F_{i}$ is the foliation values
of an smooth manifold, homemorphic to $S^{7}$ with smooth structure $S_{i}$.

The question:

> Is $F_{i}=F_{j}$, for all $i,j$?  In the other word, is the "Foliation values" a topological invariant?

Comment: Given that is seems we do not know the foliation values of actual spheres, maybe it is a bit soon to consider the exotic ones?

Comment: @Mariano thank you for your comment and your valuable information on my related question. Yes, may be it is soon, but note that in this question we do not search for the exact values of $F_{i}$. In fact we are interested to know that whether the smooth structure play an important role?That is, as I said in the question, is "Foliation values" a topological invariant. So I think the nature of this question is different from the nature of the question "What is the EXPLICIT foliation values of the 7 sphere"

Comment: Some of the exotic spheres are $S^3$-bundles over $S^4$. In this case, clearly $3\in F_i$. In general, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is *yes*: For every $k\in\{0,\dots,7\}$, every smooth manifold homeomorphic to $S^7$ admits a $k$-dimensional $C^\infty$ foliation.

[Every exotic $7$-sphere $S_i$ is parallelisable.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58131) Hence for every $m\in\{0,\dots,7\}$, every $S_i$ admits a $C^\infty$ $m$-frame field (i.e., $TS_i$ admits a trivial $C^\infty$ sub vector bundle of rank $m$). In the case $m>1$, Corollary 1 in [W. Thurston: *The theory of foliations of codimension greater than one*](https://eudml.org/doc/139581) therefore implies that $S_i$ admits a $(7-m)$-dimensional $C^\infty$ foliation. In the case $m=1$, Theorem 1a (or 1b) in [W. Thurston: *Existence of codimension-one foliations*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971047) implies that $S_i$ admits a $6$-dimensional $C^\infty$ foliation. The case $m=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  answer. I think In the  Paper of  Thurston there  is  a  restriction $k<n/2$. yes?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: Yes, but that restriction on the *co*dimension $k$ occurs in Corollary 2 (a corollary to Corollary 1), not in the Corollary 1 I cited. Corollary 2 says that in the case $k<n/2$, $S^n$ admits a foliation of codimension $k$ if and only if it admits a $k$-*plane* field. By e.g. Steenrod: *The theory of fibre bundles*, Theorem 27.16, $S^n$ admits *in the case $k<n/2$* a $k$-*plane* field (if and) only if it admits a $k$-*frame* field. Then the existence of a foliation of codimension $k$ follows from Corollary 1. But for $S^7$, we can apply Corollary 1 directly, even without $k<n/2$.