# Existence of complementary pairs of foliations on spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, foliations

Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold, $0\leq k\leq n$. We define a **$(k,n-k)$-bifoliation on $M$** to be a pair $(\mathscr{E},\mathscr{F})$ consisting of ($C^\infty$ nonsingular) foliations $\mathscr{E},\mathscr{F}$ on $M$ of dimension $k$ resp. $n-k$ which are complementary=transverse in the sense that $TM$ is the internal direct sum of $T\mathscr{E}$ and $T\mathscr{F}$.

I am interested in the case where $M$ is a sphere:

**Q1.** *For which $k$ does $S^n$ admit a $(k,n-k)$-bifoliation?*

Relevant facts and partial answers:

- Every $n$-manifold admits a unique $(0,n)$-bifoliation.

  If $(\mathscr{E},\mathscr{F})$ is a $(k,n-k)$-bifoliation, then $(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{E})$ is an $(n-k,k)$-bifoliation.

  If $S^n$ admits a $(k,n-k)$-bifoliation with $1\leq k\leq n-1$, then $n$ is odd: $TS^n$ does not split if $n$ is even.

  Every odd-dimensional $n$-manifold $M$ admits a $(1,n-1)$-bifoliation: It admits a nowhere vanishing vector field, hence an $(n-1)$-plane field. By [W. Thurston: *Existence of codimension-one foliations*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971047), it therefore admits an $(n-1)$-dimensional foliation $\mathscr{F}$. Any line subbundle $E\subseteq TM$ that is complementary to $T\mathscr{F}$ is the tangent bundle of a $1$-dimensional foliation.

  There exist $1$-dimensional foliations $\mathscr{E}$ on $S^3$ such that $S^3$ does not admit any $(1,2)$-bifoliation of the form $(\mathscr{E},\mathscr{F})$: see [Tamura/Sato: *On transverse foliations*](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1981__54__5_0), §1, Example 2.

  $TS^n$ splits off a trivial sub vector bundle of rank $k$ if and only if $k\leq 2^p+8q-1$, where $p\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $q,r\in\mathbb{N}$ are determined by $n+1 = (2r+1) 2^p 16^q$; see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres). If $TS^n$ splits off a vector bundle of rank $k\leq\frac{n}{2}$, then it splits off a trivial vector bundle of rank $k$; see Steenrod: *The topology of fibre bundles*, Theorem 27.16.

  Every homotopy class of $2$-plane fields on $S^n$ contains the tangent bundle of a foliation; see [W. Thurston: *The theory of foliations of codimension greater than one*](https://eudml.org/doc/139581) (Corollary 3).

  Let $k>\frac{n}{2}$ or $k=3$. Then $S^n$ admits a $k$-dimensional foliation if and only if $S^n$ admits a $k$-plane field: For the case $k>\frac{n}{2}$, see W. Thurston: *The theory of foliations of codimension greater than one* (Corollary 2). The obvious fibration $S^3\to S^{4m+3}\to\mathbb{HP}^m$ yields a $3$-dimensional foliation on $S^{4m+3}$.

Therefore the general problem Q1 raises the following questions (in particular about $k=2$):

**Q2.** *Can you prove for some $n$ (necessarily $n=4m+3\geq7$) and some $k\in\{2,\dots,n-2\}$ that $S^n$ admits a $(k,n-k)$-bifoliation?*

**Q3.** *Can you prove, for some $k$ and some $n$-manifold $M$, that $M$ does not admit a $(k,n-k)$-bifoliation, but admits foliations $\mathscr{E},\mathscr{F}$ of dimensions $k$ resp. $n-k$ such that $T\mathscr{F}$ is homotopic to a sub vector bundle of $TM$ which is complementary to $T\mathscr{E}$? For instance, can you prove for some $m$ that $S^{4m+3}$ does not admit a $(2,4m+1)$-bifoliation?*

**Q4.** *What is known about (non-)existence of $k$-dimensional foliations on $S^n$ in the case $4 \leq k < \frac{n}{2}$?*

In the definition of $(k,n-k)$-bifoliation, I assumed the foliations to be $C^\infty$. Can something interesting be said under other regularity assumptions, e.g. $C^1$?

Comment: To me this looks more like a research project than like a mathoverflow question :-)

Comment: @ThiKu: Answering Q1 completely would be a very ambitious research project, but asking for an answer (better than a simple "no") to Q2 *or* Q3 seems like a legitimate mathoverflow question to me, although it's maybe not an easy one. I am willing to accept an answer with a single example concerning Q2 or Q3. Also, I don't expect that the correct answer to Q4 is "nothing".

Comment: I had overlooked that Q4 has been asked before on mathoverflow. There is a 7-dimensional foliation on $S^{15}$: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154975/foliation-values-of-a-manifold#comment397139_154975).

Comment: @MarcNardmann  What about $\mathbb{C}P^2$?Does it admit a  2  dimensional real foliation? If yes is there  such a foliation whose leaves are totally geodesics  immersed submanifolds of  $\mathbb{C}P^2$ where the later is equiped with the Fubbini - study metric?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: This is off-topic here, but anyway: For $M=\mathbb{CP}^2$, assume there exist $\mathbb{R}$-vector bundles $E_0,E_1$ of rank 2 with $TM=E_0\oplus E_1$. We have $c_1(TM)=3$ and $c_2(TM)=3$, thus $w_2(TM)=1$ and $w_4(TM)=1$; see Milnor/Stasheff 14.10, 14-B. Moreover, $w(E_i)=1+w_2(E_i)$ and $w(TM) = w(E_0)w(E_1)$, thus (in $H^{2k}(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$) $1=w_2(TM)=w_2(E_0)+w_2(E_1)$ and $1=w_4(TM)=w_2(E_0)w_2(E_1)$, which is impossible. Hence $M$ does not even admit a 2-plane distribution.